# Nunjucks and an Eleventy shortcode aren't connecting to each other

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

I've written an Eleventy shortcode to take the filename of an image (as well as text for an alt tag, etc), and output a whole srcset so it becomes a responsive image.

The site's written using Nunjucks, so I need to call the shortcode from inside a Nunjucks partial.

Eleventy is returning an error, "Error: Unable to call `responsiveImageTest`, which is undefined or falsey".

In trying to diagnose the underlying error, I've ended up with the following simplified version of the code –

**previewCard.njk**
`{{ responsiveImageTest() | safe }}`

**.eleventy.js**

```
  eleventyConfig.addShortcode("responsiveImageTest", function() {
    return `<p>Check</p>`;
  });
```

**Two outcomes:**
When I include the curved braces in previewCard.njk, Eleventy says it's unable to call responsiveImageTest.
When I remove the curved braces, Eleventy compiles just fine, but the shortcode doesn't return anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the wrong syntax to use a shortcode with eleventy + nunjucks. As per eleventy documentation (https://www.11ty.dev/docs/shortcodes/, in "View this example in:" you can click in "nunjucks" to change the template language of the example) you could try something as follow:

previewCard.njk

```
{% responsiveImageTest "fileName" %}
```

.eleventy.js

```
eleventyConfig.addShortcode("responsiveImageTest", function() {
  ...
});
```

Also you might want to check eleventy's image plugin that helps with image transformations, including responsive output: https://www.11ty.dev/docs/plugins/image/